# collapse hide/show function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Some times its working properly and sometimes it gives me below error.

> TypeError: $(...).collapse is not a function

```
$('.collapse:visible').collapse('hide').siblings('.accordion-heading ').find('a').addClass('collapsed')
```

---

**Complete script:**

```
var b = true;

function moreFilters() {
  if (b) {
    $('#accordion3').show()
    $('.collapse:visible').collapse('hide').siblings('.accordion-heading ').find('a').addClass('collapsed')
    document.getElementById('moreFilterImg').src = '../common/img/filter-less.png';
    b = false;
  } else {
    $('#accordion3').hide()
    $('.collapse:visible').collapse('hide').siblings('.accordion-heading ').find('a').addClass('collapsed')
    document.getElementById('moreFilterImg').src = '../common/img/filter-more.png';
    b = true;
  }
}
```

This is my code can anyone help :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `.slideToggle()`?

Comment: There is no `collapse()` function in jQuery. Do you have a custom function ??

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `collapse`? remove a class? add a class? hide the element? You might need `.toggleClass`, `.removeClass`, `.css('display','none')` instead of `collapse`.

Comment: I am trying to show more filters, however i want to hide filter values (elements) under filter labels, so that it does not look 'clunky'. :)

Comment: As we wanted to hide more number of elements we thought of using bootstrap collapse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since there is no function `collapse()` in jQuery, I think you should replace this code:

```
$('.collapse:visible').collapse('hide').siblings('.accordion-heading ').find('a').addClass('collapsed')
```

with this one:

```
$('.collapse:visible').hide().siblings('.accordion-heading ').find('a').addClass('collapsed')
```

Comment: Thank you so much Viktor its working properly now 
and my mistake we are using bootstrap collapse and i mentioned it as jquery function.

Answer (score 1):

.colapse is not a valid jquery function. Try .hide() instead
In your situation however I would recommend .slideToggle()
http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/